# Can't run ./gradlew genSources

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I'm following a tutorial to make a Fabric mod for Minecraft. I'm trying to run genSources but it gives this error.

```
PS C:\Users\Voxe\Minecraft\Plugins\AllianceClient> ./gradlew genSources

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Voxe\Minecraft\Plugins\AllianceClient\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '1.2-SNAPSHOT']
> Failed to apply plugin 'fabric-loom'.
   > You are using an outdated version of Java (8). Java 17 or higher is required.
     The JAVA_HOME environment variable is currently set to (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221).

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

My `JAVA_HOME` is not set to `jdk1.8.0_221`, but `jdk-17.0.1`, and so is the variable in the PATH.

Comment: Can you remove `jdk-17.0.1` from your path? If its earlier in the path, then it might be getting picked up first.

Comment: What does `$env:JAVA_HOME` say?

Comment: What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @g00se I'm on Windows.

Comment: Clearly, the shell you're using and the one used by Gradle aren't the same. I'm not sure why, and no one can tell you without actually looking into your system.

Comment: @Voxel, that's a Powershell shortcut

Comment: @g00se Oh. It says C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221... I wonder why it's different.

Comment: Make sure you don't have some sort of Powershell profile file with some old values in it

Comment: @g00se I've just created this project. I don't know how to fix this. This is inside the Terminal tab in IntelliJ.

Comment: OK. I don't use IntelliJ so can't tell what it does for/to its Powershell shell. My first recourse would be to open a 'real' terminal. I would recommend using Powershell in due course but for now I would open cmd.exe in the build directory. Do that and let us know what you get for `echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%`

Comment: @g00se Running `gradlew genSources` in Command Prompt in the same directory gives the same error.

Comment: You didn't answer the question

Comment: @g00se Oh, sorry. The output is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221`.

Comment: OK then, so that's more evidence (from an entirely different source) that you're wrong about *My JAVA_HOME is not set to jdk1.8.0_221, but jdk-17.0.1, and so is the variable in the PATH.*

Comment: @g00se I just noticed something - when I run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` in another directory, it outputs `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`, which is what I tried to do to fix this earlier. It's somehow different than in that directory.

Comment: That's a path for an entirely different OS and not Windows ;) One thing you could check is that you don't have two different values set for both User and System. I personally never set user env vars in Windows. If you still can't get it to behave, you *should* be able to override the incorrect env var by setting it directly in the console before your Gradle command with `set JAVA_HOME="correct path quoted like this if containing spaces"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix this:

You can set an environment variable in PowerShell (there's a difference in the environment variables between the PowerShell in the project and command prompt for some reason) with `$env:VARIABLE_NAME='C:\path\to\folder` and verify that it's correct with `dir env:`.